# How do I say to Twig where to look for the template files?

Tags: theming

I want to add another path where the templates are stored. In standard PHP I'd use `$loader->addPath('../path/to/templates')`. I found [`Twig_Loader_Filesystem::addPath()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor!twig!twig!lib!Twig!Loader!Filesystem.php/function/Twig_Loader_Filesystem%3A%3AaddPath/8.2.x), but I have no clue where and how to use it.

Is there any hook?

Comment: Can you explain the issue you are trying to solve? You want to store your theme outside of `<drupalroot>/themes`?

Comment: Well, I am creating living styleguides and reusable (Frontend & Backend) components system for internal use of our company. To keep the setup in a same way for every project type (Symfony, WP, Drupal...) and let styleguides be easily accessible I want to place the templates folder in the root. But this is unrelated to the question itself. My question is - how can I addPath.

Comment: If you insist on using `addPath` I cannot help you. But you might succeed using a symlink from your theme to the shared folder.

Comment: Symlink is pretty obvious solution but it's not clean enough. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

What you found is the class used from Twig to load the template files from the file system, but what Drupal uses is its own class derived from that,  [`Drupal\Core\Template\Loader\FileSystemLoader`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21Loader%21FilesystemLoader.php/class/FilesystemLoader/8.2.x), which is the default class implementing the [twig.loader.filesystem](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/twig.loader.filesystem/8.2.x) service. Its only purpose is adding a namespace for each theme and module enabled from a Drupal site, so that is possible to reference a template file as @block/block.html.twig.

For how I understand it, replacing the class implementing that service with a class derived from the default implementation, you could be able to reference 
a template in a different directory with, for example, @external_directory/template.html.twig.

See  [`FilesystemLoader::__construct()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21Loader%21FilesystemLoader.php/function/FilesystemLoader%3A%3A__construct/8.2.x) for how Drupal adds new namespaces, and [Altering existing services, providing dynamic services](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services) for how to alter that service to use a different class.